# Upgrade root (also boot) filesystem from ext3 to ext4 on Debian

Tags: filesystems, ext3, ext4, debian-squeeze

After upgrading a Debian system from 5.0 to 6.0 (Lenny to Sqeeze), how do I go about upgrading the root filesystem (which in this case is also boot) from ext3 to ext4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was no big deal at all, here's what I did:

1. Edit `/etc/fstab`, replacing "ext3" with "ext4" for my root filesystem.  (I also removed "barrier=1", which is now the default on ext4.)
2. Reboot into single user mode with read only root filesystem.
3. Run `tune2fs -O extents,uninit_bg,dir_index /dev/DEV`
4. Reboot, again into single user mode with read only root filesystem.  (Observe some mount warnings.)
5. Run `e2fsck -fDC0 /dev/DEV` to patch up the filesystem.
6. Reboot normally.

Most of this was taken from [here](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Howto).

Comment: FYI the EXT4 Howto URL is now https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/articles/e/x/t/Ext4_Howto_d00b.html

Comment: You'll probably want to convert the files and directories on the filesystem to use "extents" too, by using `chattr +e file` on everything.

Answer (score 0):

additionaly to **pauldoo**'s answer

1. you might need to add `rootfstype=ext4` to kernel boot options
2. if you've converted a fairly old ext2 to ext4, it might be lacking online resize capability with the only solution - create new ext4 fs and then move your files there (sad, but true)
3. if you've converted a fairly old ext2 to ext4, you might notice a .journal file at the root. it does not appear on other mount points, since `fsck -f` hides it automatically. Sadly it canot do the same to / mount point - you need live cd or any other running system to hide this `.journal` node

PS still actual for wheezy